# Why does this not raise a compilation error? (Mongoose, Typescript, MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I'm currently setting up a MERN project in Typescript, and I'm wondering why the following doesn't create a compilation error in TS.

Here's my model:

```
import { Document, Schema, model } from "mongoose";
export interface Hello extends Document {
  name: string;
}

const helloSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
  },
});

const helloModel = model<Hello>("Hello", helloSchema);

export default helloModel;
```

then used like this:

```
import express from "express";
import helloModel from "./model";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hi");
});

const x = new helloModel({ age: 1 }); <===== no errors here

app.listen(7000);
```

I would expect there to be compilation errors saying that x doesn't conform to the interface. Am I using the model incorrectly? I'm fairly new to MongoDB and Typescript if that's not immediately clear (I hope not).

Many thanks to anyone who can explain.

EDIT FOLLOW-UP
I've found this in the @types files:

```
/**
     * Model constructor
     * Provides the interface to MongoDB collections as well as creates document instances.
     * @param doc values with which to create the document
     * @event error If listening to this event, it is emitted when a document
     *   was saved without passing a callback and an error occurred. If not
     *   listening, the event bubbles to the connection used to create this Model.
     * @event index Emitted after Model#ensureIndexes completes. If an error
     *   occurred it is passed with the event.
     * @event index-single-start Emitted when an individual index starts within
     *   Model#ensureIndexes. The fields and options being used to build the index
     *   are also passed with the event.
     * @event index-single-done Emitted when an individual index finishes within
     *   Model#ensureIndexes. If an error occurred it is passed with the event.
     *   The fields, options, and index name are also passed.
     */
    new (doc?: any): T;
```

So that doc?: any is why there's no compile error. Does this mean that generally when we're joining our Mongo schemas with our TS interfaces we can only have type checking on Read, Update and Delete rather than on Create?

Comment: I think you are assuming that the driver has strict typing information, and I would verify whether this assumption is in fact accurate.

Comment: Hi @D.SM, thanks for this - could you please explain further? Sorry to be ignorant. Having gone through the .d.ts file and tried messing around with it it;s pretty clear that doc?: any is necessary here, I'm just trying to work out why that is

Comment: my impression of the situation is the driver was written in js (being rewritten in ts now) and typing annotations were community maintained. As such the annotations don't necessarily have types specified everywhere they *could* be specified.

Comment: Thanks @D.SM. That would make sense. Interestingly, in the typing file I tried switching new(doc?: any): T to new(doc?: T):T (where T extends mongoose.Document, and then when I tried to instantiate a new document the TS compiler wanted all of the associated parts of the Document interface as well as my interface as a parameter (which makes sense). I just find it interesting that create() is typechecked when it just means new().save()...

Answer (score 0):

You're right with `doc?: any`, we can't have typechecking on create method. It will throw an error when you will try to save it to the database and only because schema check.

Comment: thanks for this but I'm afraid I still don't understand. Why can't there be typechecking on the create method?

Comment: Also @Doomel there **is** typechecking on the create() method, but not just when a new document is instantiated.